# Breaking on JScript runtime error : permission denied in IE7 on $(':text')

Tags: jquery, security, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I'm getting a permission denied error only in IE7, when I'm doing ***$(':text')***.
I'm using **jQuery-1.6.2** and it's working perfectly fine in all the other browsers and even IE>=8;

Please help...

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that ***$(':text')*** works with **jquery-1.4.2**

It has stopped working in IE7 since I have upgraded jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `$("input[type='text'])` this is the same query just a lot faster since :text evaluates to *:text which is slow.

Comment: SWEET, that works. But I still don't know why $("[type='text']") is not working !!!

Comment: I know the documentation mentions that of 1.5.2 that selector will select all input which do not have a type defined as well as inputs with type=text. Maybe it is doing something odd there.

Comment: I see. Whatever the reason, you made my day. I've been doing a lot of hair pulling for a while there. Thanks for the help.